# Toggle state to trigger a function with a button in Python - loops on and off though

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I’m trying to use a button, in this case an Amazon Dash Button, to trigger two functions - i.e. push once it activates one function, push again activates another.

I have tried setting a state to the button and then changing the state from False to True, but the while loop simply seems to repeat triggering the action to turn on and off.

I suspect this is because the loop is going to the start, seeing the state is set to False by default and then going from there. However, I’m stuck when trying to figure out where I need to put the state so that it works.

Here’s the relevant part of my code so far:

```
def button_pressed_dash():
try:
    socket_on = False
    while True:
        if not socket_on:
            both_on()
            socket_on = True
        elif socket_on:
            both_off()
            socket_on = False
        time.sleep(5)
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    os._exit(1)
```

Comment: Please indicate what `both_on()` and `both_off()`does.

Comment: I didn’t want to include as it would make the example infinitely larger. For the sake of this, it could just say `print(“Both on”)` as I know the functions work, but it’s the loop that seems to be broken as I believe the variable is set before the loop, so it resets the state each time. Does that help?